# Davies-Meyer Construction

Tags: hash

For implementing a hash function, we can use Davies-Meyer Construction. In Katz crypto book it is written:

Let $F$ be a block cipher with $n$-bit key length and $l$-bit block length. We can then define the compression function $h:\{0,1\}^{l+n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^l$ by $h(k,x)=F_k(x)\oplus x$.

My question is what is the point of XORing $x$ with $F_k(x)$?

Comment: Because in this way it can have proven security in the Ideal Cipher Model.

Comment: Is $k$ the secret key or it is part of the input?

Comment: [The key is the message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer). There is no secret key on Hash functions except they are keyed Hash functions like HMAC.

Comment: Thanks, @kelalaka! If $k$ is not secret, then the above formula completely makes sense.